# Check memory status of every node in alerts for prometheus

Tags: alert, prometheus

I want to write a alert query for prometheus.
Which will raise alert if any node is consuming memory more than specific % of memory.

I want to dynamically take node and check memory status of it.

1. read all nodes
2. loop over each node with query

   sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{job="kubernetes-nodes", id="/", instance="$node"}) / sum(machine_memory_bytes{job="kubernetes-nodes", instance="$node"}) * 100

this alert works if i provide static name of node

```
 ALERT HighMemoryAlert
  IF 100 * sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{job="kubernetes-nodes", id="/",instance="ip-170-10-10-17.eu-west-1.compute.internal"}) / sum(machine_memory_bytes{job="kubernetes-nodes",instance="ip-170-10-10-17.eu-west-1.compute.internal"}) > 90
  FOR 15m
  LABELS {
    service = "k8s",
    severity = "warning"
  }
  ANNOTATIONS {
    summary = "HighMemoryAlert"
  }
```

I dont want to add ip statically as k8s node ip can b changed over the period of time if any node crashes and created with different ip

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is aggregate up while keeping the instance label, so

```
  sum by (instance)(container_memory_usage_bytes{job="kubernetes-nodes", id="/"}) 
/ 
  sum by (instance)(machine_memory_bytes{job="kubernetes-nodes"}) * 100
```